# How to append custom fields to HTTP Request header using Request class

Tags: http, typescript, angular

How to append custom fields to HTTP Request header using Request class in Angular2?
I found posts which solve similar problems, but they don't use Request class.

My code is the below.

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('foo', 'bar');

let req: any = {
  method : RequestMethod.Get,
  url    : '/test.json',
  headers: headers,
};

// this.http is Http instance variable.
this.http.request(new Request(req)).map((res: any) => res.json());
```

This is very simple code.
But when executing this, I couldn't find custom fields in HTTP request header using Developer Tools of Google Chrome.

Referenced: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/Request-class.html

---

It's possible to reproduce this issue.
The below code should get XHR 400 errors, but it's not problem. But note that the request header don't have custom fields.

http://plnkr.co/edit/arCFx69V9H1Cl0pJXBzO?p=preview

Comment: Sorry, the cause is in server side processing. I've already solved.

Answer (score 6):

You probably forgot to import the `Headers` class:

```
import {Http, Headers, ...} from 'angular2/http';
```

You could also use the following code:

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('foo', 'bar');

this.http.get('test.json', { headers }).map((res: any) => res.json());
```

Moreover don't forget to subscribe on the returned observable to execute the request since observables are lazy:

```
let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('foo', 'bar');

this.http.get('test.json', { headers })
  .map((res: any) => res.json())
  .subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. Of course, I wrote it and completed to transpile TypeScript files without errors. But this doesn't work....

Comment: Do you subscribe on the request observable? I updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, I subscribed it. But I couldn't find to append custom fields to request header in Developer Tools.

Comment: ah, I want to use `http.request` instead of `http.get` or `http.post` , therefore I must use Request class.

Comment: Which version of Angular2 do you use?

Comment: Using this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/bTClKR8kfAlAlIh1gL37?p=preview, I can see the custom header in the request headers...